# jquery mobile select click handler

Tags: html, django, jquery-mobile

I have a small web app that is using Django, Dajaxice, and JQuery Mobile.

I've created a drop down menu containing all possible timezones. I want to make it so that when a user selects a timezone from the dropdown menu, and clicks a button, the button fetches whatever option has been selected and, using Dajaxice (I'll handle this), passes it to a MySQL database.

As I'm new to JQuery mobile, and JavaScript...I need some help writing the click handler for the select and the button. Code follows:

```
    <!-- TimeZone select section -->
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="timezone-select" class="select">Choose Timezone:</label>
    <select name="timezone-select" id="timezone-select" data-inline="true">
        {%for x in timezones%}
            <option value="{{x}}" id="option_{{forloop.counter}}" >{{x}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
</div>  

<!-- Sumbit TimeZone -->
<div>
    <a data-role="button" id="storeTimezone" data-inline="true">Store Timezone</a>
    <h1 id="storedTimezone">Stored Timezone: </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the selected option with this jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var yourTimezone = $('#selectID').find(":selected").text();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped me come up with this.   $("#storeTimezone").click(function(){
   var yourTimezone = $('#timezone-select').find(":selected").text();
   storeTimezone();
   console.log("Timezone Selected: " + yourTimezone);
  })